# DataFrame to LabeledPoint: df.collect() Error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I met a problem when I transform my DataFrame to a LabeledPoint RDD, and his error bothered me several days. Hope some of you can help me to solve it. Thanks a lot!

I want to transform a DataFrame to a RDD[labeledPoint] since I need to train a Random Forest model. First I dropped all rows with null value:

```
def na_drop(data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = {

    return data.na.drop()
}
```

And this is how I transform a DataFrame to RDD.

```
def to_labeledPoint(df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame,
                    target_name: String) : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint] = {

    val featInd = df.columns.map(df.columns.indexOf(_))

    val targetInd = df.columns.indexOf(target_name) 

    var result = df.rdd.map(r => LabeledPoint(r.getDouble(targetInd),
                                                Vectors.dense(featInd.map(r.getDouble(_)).toArray)
                                                )
                            )       
    return result
}
```

Main function part:

```
// to_labeledPoint is a method in hive class

var data = hive.to_labeledPoint(data_after_na_drop, "outmoney", List("action",
                                                        "userid",
                                                        "paytype"))

data.collect()
// or run data_l.take(5).foreach(println)
```

When I run the code above, I get error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 
aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, 
most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 5797, rz-data-
hdp-dn3024.rz.sankuai.com): java.lang.ClassCastException: 
java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

I cannot find the reason for this error, so if you have any suggestions I will be really appreciated.

Comment: How can the 2-argument `to_labeledPoint` be used with 3 arguments?! My understanding of Scala says it's not possible.

Comment: sample inputs update on the question shall get you quicker answers. :) And Jacek is right about to_labeledPoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the type of the column you use as the feature vector is of type `Long` yet you expect it to be of type `Double`.

I strongly suggest reviewing the schema of your Dataset using `printSchema` and fix it.

In your case, you should review the schema of `data_after_na_drop`.

```
data_after_na_drop.printSchema
```